# Eclipse + OpenOCD + gdb: Attach to running target

Tags: gdb, openocd

How can I attach to a running MCU target with OpenOCD + gdb? It seems to default to flashing the binary and performing a reset, and unchecking all options under Startup for resetting and flashing results in that no source code or symbols can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you got it. But you can let the symbols/source load but not let the executable load. Disable the "Load executable". The two are unrelated.

But, there is no way to detach as this is not implemented in OpenOCD. The requirement for a gdb-server is to undo any changes made to enable debugging (remove breakpoints, etc.) and let the program continue. This does not seem possible.